# Variable not define after exec('variable = value')

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm quite stuck on this one ^^. I have a view in which I use a function named modifier_dico which is inside a file named fonctions.py. The 2 first lines of modifier_dico are as follows :

```
def modifier_dico(tweet,nom_dico, dico_cat):
    exec('dico= {}')
```

My view looks like :

```
def classer_tweet(request):
    modifier_dico(tweet.text,"dico_status.txt", {})
```

When I try to access this view, I get `name 'dico' is not defined` on Django's debug page.

But when I look at [the local vars of modifier_dico in the traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzxJP.jpg), I have the variable **dico** with the value **{}**

It looks like `exec()` is not working as I expect.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You didn't specify what namespace to set the name in, so the name was set in the scope of the `fonctions.modifier_dico()` function, not `classer_tweet()`. From the [`exec()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope.

You'd have to pass in a different dictionary for the name to be set in as a second argument:

```
exec('dico = {}', namespace)
```

You can't use `exec()` to set locals in a function, unless the name was *already* assigned to in a given function. This is a hard limitation due optimisations to how a local namespace in a function is accessed. From the same documentation:

> **Note:** The default *locals* act as described for function `locals()` below: modifications to the default *locals* dictionary should not be attempted. Pass an explicit *locals* dictionary if you need to see effects of the code on *locals* after function `exec()` returns.

and from the linked [`locals()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

As such you can't use `exec()` to set additional local variables in your view function. You really should use dictionaries anyway for arbitrary namespaces.

You may still see alterations in the `locals()` dictionary, but because the function returns a *reflection of the actual locals in one direction*, that local is not actually available in the function itself. In other words, the actual locals of a function are copied to a dictionary that `locals()` returns, additions to that dictionary are not copied back:

```
>>> def no_local_foo():
...     exec('foo = "bar"')
...     print(locals())
...     foo
...
>>> no_local_foo()
{'foo': 'bar'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in no_local_foo
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```