# Variable Not Defined after using exec

Tags: python

i am trying to write code to set variable 'length' to the length of a list called the value of split[c], and have a random str from that list be printed.

Here's the code:

```
spit=input().split(' ')
c=0

#the bit i am having trouble with
def spitter():
    exec('length=len('+spit[c]+')-1')
    rand=random.randrange(0,length)
    exec('print('+spit[c]+'[rand])')

while not c==len(spit):
    spitter()
    c=c+1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable not define after exec('variable = value')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336702/variable-not-define-after-execvariable-value)

Comment: but `len(spit[c])` will always be 1, so why are you using `exec()` inthe first place?

Comment: also the `" "` inside `split()` is redundant

Comment: Why are you asking the user for the name of a variable? Use a `dict` to map user input to the value you want to split.

Comment: yes, @chepner i am trying to ask the user for the name of the variable. i know i could use a dictionary but i am now curious as to why the code above doesn't work.

Comment: `exec` is ... tricky. Because the code generator doesn't know what `exec` is going to do, `length` is treated as a global variable here, but `exec` ends up defining a *local* variable. You could pass `globals()` as a second argument to `exec`, which would cause it to use the global scope as both the global *and* local scope for the code being executed. But it's better to just avoid using `exec` unless there is no alternative.